# AWS route 53 record alias "Connection is not private" when using path parameter

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-route53

I have a a word press website running on an EC2 instance with an application load balancer in front of it.

I also have a certificate from AWS certificate manager for "example.com". This certificate is attached to the ALB "HTTPS" listener.

I also have two route 53 records, one alias to the ALB and another alias to redirect "www" traffic:

1. example.com. A ALIAS dualstack.[id].us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com.
2. www.example.com. A ALIAS example.com.

My issue is when trying to access the website, everything is fine except when path parameters are provided, in that case I get the "Your connection is not private" browser error. See example warning here: https://prnt.sc/opip7d

- example.com (Everything is fine, page is loaded properly)
- www.exemple.com (Everything is fine, I get redirected to exemple.com and page loads)
- www.exemple.com/test (NOT fine, I get the "Your connection is not private" warning)

Can anyone shine light on why this would be happening? Shouldn't route53 automatically redirect any traffic regardless?

Comment: Please make sure you put both `example.com` and `www.example.com` in the certificate when you request it from ACM.

Comment: Do you have any listeners for `opip7d` path?

Comment: Also make sure that on that page everything else (static content) is also https and there is no http request. You can check that in developer view of chrome

Comment: @jellycsc I added a new Certificate to the load balancer with "example.com" as well as "*.example.com" and everything seems to be fine now. Little confuse since I would assume that the redirection requests would come from route 53 and not my load balancer.

Comment: Route 53 can't do redirection. What you configured was just a CNAME record.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use listeners rules of AWS ALB to redirect:

```
HTTP 80: default action 
IF Requests otherwise not routed THEN Redirect to HTTPS://#{host}:443/#{path}?#{query}
                                 Status code:HTTP_301

HTTPS:443
IF Host is www.example.com THEN Redirect to HTTPS://example.com:443/#{path}?#{query}
                           Status code:HTTP_301
```